# Resizing a rotated container in flutter from corners and middle points ( 8 points)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, matrix, transformation

I am developing an shape editor in flutter. For that, I need to add a feature of adding shapes dynamically to the screen. Each of them should be able to independently scale, position, and rotate. There should be an anchor point like in word or in Photoshop to indicate the active shapes and to scale and rotate them. The shape should be positioned with drag and drop.

I found this answer :
[Rotate and resize container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68112202/how-can-we-achieve-the-positioned-lines-while-dragging-widget-in-flutter)
But the answer only rotate the shape from the center, I want to scale the shape from the corners also.

The code :

```
class FooResizer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FooResizerState createState() => _FooResizerState();
}

class _FooResizerState extends State<FooResizer> with TickerProviderStateMixin, ChangeNotifier {
  Sizer currentSizer;
  double angle = 0.0;
  AnimationController ctrl;

  final Map<String, Sizer> sizers = {
    'l': Sizer('l', Alignment.centerLeft, {'t': 0.5, 'b': 0.5, 'M': 0.5}),
    't': Sizer('t', Alignment.topCenter, {'l': 0.5, 'r': 0.5, 'M': 0.5}),
    'r': Sizer('r', Alignment.centerRight, {'t': 0.5, 'b': 0.5, 'R': 1.0, 'M': 0.5}),
    'b': Sizer('b', Alignment.bottomCenter, {'l': 0.5, 'r': 0.5, 'R': 1.0, 'M': 0.5}),
    'R': Sizer('R', Alignment.bottomRight, {}),
    'M': Sizer('M', Alignment.center, {}),
  };

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ctrl = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), value: 1.0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRect(
      child: ColoredBox(
        color: Colors.black12,
        // CustomMultiChildLayoutPainter:
        // https://gist.github.com/pskink/0f82724b41d9ebe89604782fbf62fe03#file-multi_layout_painter-dart-L447
        child: CustomMultiChildLayoutPainter(
          delegate: _FooResizerDelegate(sizers, this),
          children: [
            LayoutId(
              id: 'body',
              child: AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: this,
                builder: (ctx, child) {
                  return Transform.rotate(
                    angle: angle,
                    child: child,
                  );
                },
                child: Material(color: Colors.grey[300], elevation: 4, child: FlutterLogo()),
              ),
            ),
            ...sizers.values.map(_sizerBuilder),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _sizerBuilder(Sizer sizer) {
    final colors = {
      'M': Colors.orange,
      'R': Colors.teal,
    };
    return LayoutId(
      id: sizer.id,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPanStart: (details) => _panStart(sizer),
        onPanUpdate: _panUpdate,
        onPanEnd: _panEnd,
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: ctrl,
          builder: (context, child) {
            final color = colors[sizer.id] ?? Colors.green;
            return Opacity(
              opacity: currentSizer == sizer? 1.0 : Curves.ease.transform(ctrl.value),
              child: Container(
                decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                  shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(width: lerpDouble(0.0, 2.0, ctrl.value), color: Colors.black38)),
                  color: currentSizer == sizer? Color.lerp(Colors.deepPurple, color, ctrl.value) : color,
                  shadows: [BoxShadow.lerp(BoxShadow(spreadRadius: 2, blurRadius: 4, offset: Offset(2, 2)), null, ctrl.value)],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _panStart(Sizer sizer) {
    currentSizer = sizer;
    ctrl.reverse();
  }

  _panUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    assert(currentSizer != null);
    if (currentSizer.id == 'M') {
      // move
      sizers.values.forEach((sizer) => sizer.center += details.delta);
    } else
    if (currentSizer.id == 'R') {
      // rotate
      final localCenter = sizers['M'].center;
      final globalCenter = (context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).localToGlobal(localCenter);

      final angle0 = (details.globalPosition - details.delta - globalCenter).direction;
      final angle1 = (details.globalPosition - globalCenter).direction;
      final deltaAngle = angle1 - angle0;
      sizers.values
        .where((sizer) => sizer.id != 'M')
        .forEach((sizer) {
          final vector = sizer.center - localCenter;
          sizer.center = localCenter + Offset.fromDirection(vector.direction + deltaAngle, vector.distance);
        });
      angle += deltaAngle;
    } else {
      // resize
      final adjustedAngle = angle + currentSizer.angleAdjustment;
      final rotatedDistance = details.delta.distance * math.cos(details.delta.direction - adjustedAngle);
      final vector = Offset.fromDirection(adjustedAngle, rotatedDistance);
      currentSizer.center += vector;
      currentSizer.dependents.forEach((id, factor) => sizers[id].center += vector * factor);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  _panEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    assert(currentSizer != null);
    // currentSizer = null;
    ctrl.forward();
  }
}


class _FooResizerDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutPainterDelegate {
  static const SIZE = 48.0;
  final Map<String, Sizer> sizers;

  _FooResizerDelegate(this.sizers, Listenable relayout) : super(relayout: relayout);

  @override
  void performLayout(Size size) {
    sizers['M'].center ??= init(size);

    for (var sizer in sizers.values) {
      layoutChild(sizer.id, BoxConstraints.tight(Size(SIZE, SIZE)));
      positionChild(sizer.id, sizer.center - Offset(SIZE / 2, SIZE / 2));
    }
    final w = (sizers['l'].center - sizers['r'].center).distance;
    final h = (sizers['t'].center - sizers['b'].center).distance;
    layoutChild('body', BoxConstraints.tight(Size(w, h)));
    positionChild('body', sizers['M'].center - Offset(w / 2, h / 2));
  }

  Offset init(Size size) {
    final rect = (Offset.zero & size).deflate(24);
    print('init rect: $rect');
    for (var sizer in sizers.values) {
      sizer
        ..center = sizer.alignment.withinRect(rect)
        ..angleAdjustment = sizer.alignment.x == 0? math.pi / 2 : 0;
    }
    return sizers['M'].center;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(covariant MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) => true;

  @override
  void foregroundPaint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final w = (sizers['r'].center - sizers['l'].center).distance;
    final h = (sizers['b'].center - sizers['t'].center).distance;
    final rect = Rect.fromCenter(center: sizers['M'].center, width: w, height: h);
    final angle = (sizers['r'].center - sizers['l'].center).direction;
    final matrix = Matrix4.identity()
      ..translate(rect.center.dx, rect.center.dy)
      ..rotateZ(angle)
      ..translate(-rect.center.dx, -rect.center.dy);
    final transformedRect = MatrixUtils.transformRect(matrix, rect);
    final points = [
      Offset(transformedRect.left, 0), Offset(transformedRect.left, size.height),
      Offset(0, transformedRect.top), Offset(size.width, transformedRect.top),
      Offset(transformedRect.right, 0), Offset(transformedRect.right, size.height),
      Offset(0, transformedRect.bottom), Offset(size.width, transformedRect.bottom),
    ];
    canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.lines, points, Paint());
  }
}

class Sizer {
  final String id;
  final Alignment alignment;
  final Map<String, double> dependents;
  Offset center;
  double angleAdjustment;
  Sizer(this.id, this.alignment, this.dependents);
}
```

**The result :**

[image: result of the code]

**what I am trying to achieve :**

[image]