# Flutter: How to keep offset when resize widget after rotated?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-positioned

My main goal is, to create a flexible widget with features.

1. manage widget position.
2. rotate widget.
3. Resize the widget from all sides.

1 and 2, I've managed to make. but the 3rd point, when the widget finishes rotating and resizing the widget, the position will change and be erratic.

i really need you guys help.
thanks

[image]

this is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const TestingDesign2(),
    );
  }
}

class Item{
  Size size;
  Offset offset;
  double rotation;
  var parentKey;
  Item({required this.parentKey, required this.size, required this.offset, required this.rotation });
}

class TestingDesign2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestingDesign2({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestingDesign2> createState() => _TestingDesign2State();
}

class _TestingDesign2State extends State<TestingDesign2> {

    
  Item item = new Item(
  parentKey: new GlobalKey(),
  offset: Offset(10,10),
    size: Size(150,150),
    rotation: 0
  );
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Testing design 2")),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.blueAccent.withOpacity(0.5),
         
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
           
            children: [ItemTesting(key: item.parentKey, item:item)],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class ItemTesting extends StatefulWidget {
  Item item;
  ItemTesting({super.key, required this.item});

  @override
  State<ItemTesting> createState() => _ItemTestingState();
}

class _ItemTestingState extends State<ItemTesting> {
  
  double offsetAngle = 0;
  bool isRotate = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _Item();
  }

  Widget _Item() {
    return Positioned(
      left: widget.item.offset.dx,
      top: widget.item.offset.dy,
      child: Transform.rotate(
        angle: widget.item.rotation,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: widget.item.size.height,
          width: widget.item.size.width,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onPanStart: onPanStart,
                onPanUpdate: onPanUpdate,
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                onPanEnd: (details) {
                  isRotate = false;
                },
                onPanCancel: () {
                  isRotate = false;
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: widget.item.size.height,
                  width: widget.item.size.width,
                ),
              ),
              IgnorePointer(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: ClipOval(
                      child: Container(
                          height: 25,
                          width: 25,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: Icon(Icons.rotate_right_outlined))),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                      onPanUpdate: resizeRight,
                      child: Container(
                          height: 25,
                          width: 25,
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)))),
              Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                      onPanUpdate: resizeBottom,
                      child: Container(
                          height: 25,
                          width: 25,
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward))))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  var touchPosition = Offset.zero;
  onPanStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    Offset centerOfGestureDetector = Offset(widget.item.size.width / 2, widget.item.size.height / 2);
    final touchPositionFromCenter =
        details.localPosition - centerOfGestureDetector;
    offsetAngle = touchPositionFromCenter.direction - widget.item.rotation;

    final RenderBox referenceBox =
        widget.item.parentKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    var x = referenceBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);

    touchPosition = Offset(x.dx, x.dy + 55);
    // top right
    if (details.localPosition.dx > (widget.item.size.width - 25) &&
        details.localPosition.dy <= 25) {
      isRotate = true;
    }
  }

  onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    if (isRotate) {
      Offset centerOfGestureDetector = Offset(widget.item.size.width / 2, widget.item.size.height / 2);
      final touchPositionFromCenter =
          details.localPosition - centerOfGestureDetector;

      widget.item.rotation = touchPositionFromCenter.direction - offsetAngle;
    } else {
      var positionG = widget.item.offset + details.globalPosition;
      var positiong2 = positionG - touchPosition;
      widget.item.offset = (positiong2 - widget.item.offset);
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

//------------------------------------------------ resize widget
  void resizeRight(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      widget.item.size = Size(widget.item.size.width + details.delta.dx, widget.item.size.height);
    });
  }

  void resizeBottom(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      widget.item.size = Size(widget.item.size.width, widget.item.size.height + details.delta.dy);
    });
  }
}
```

https://dartpad.dev/?id=b1cb4617d4dd1a25e815a01135f95222

Comment: you can borrow some ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/a/68114162/2252830

Comment: @pskink i have tried it, but the code doesn't seem to work at all. any new update for that code?

Comment: run it without null safety

Comment: @pskink thanks but, I really need null safety. btw, i managed to keep the position while resizing the widget. but still shaking due to rendering delay, check this. what do you think ? https://dartpad.dev/?id=d527e5b7a86711849eb2274cea7b178a

Comment: "but, I really need null safety" - so convert it to null safety, the automatic canversion is done by `dart migrate` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Rotational Offsets

You can compensate for the rotation by offsetting the position proportional to the `cos` and `sin` of the angle.

First, to use `cos` and `sin` functions, import the 'dart:math' library at the beginning:

```
import 'dart:math';
```

Then in your `resizeRight` function:

```
  void resizeRight(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      widget.item.size = Size(widget.item.size.width + details.delta.dx, widget.item.size.height);
      var angle = widget.item.rotation;
      var rotationalOffset = Offset(cos(angle) - 1, sin(angle)) * details.delta.dx / 2;
      widget.item.offset += rotationalOffset;
    });
  }
```

Likewise, in your `resizeBottom` function:

```
  void resizeBottom(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      widget.item.size = Size(widget.item.size.width, widget.item.size.height + details.delta.dy);
      var angle = widget.item.rotation;
      var rotationalOffset = Offset(-sin(angle), cos(angle) - 1) * details.delta.dy / 2;
      widget.item.offset += rotationalOffset;
    });
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much i really appreciate it. You make my day

Comment: Hello @Steve, what if the button is located at the corners, e.g. BottomRight? What would be the correct formula to get the correct position for that?

Comment: @snap You can combine the two resize functions, either by combining the x, y components for `widget.item.size` and `rotationalOffset` or alternatively just calling both functions, i.e. `void resizeBottomRight(DragUpdateDetails details) { resizeRight(details); resizeBottom(details); }`

Comment: Managed to do it by calling the two functions. But what if I want it to use the former, what will be the `rotationalOffset`'s value? Sorry I'm not knowledgeable with trigonometry at the moment :\

Comment: @Steve Can you please help me to resize from `topCenter`, `leftCenter`, `topLeft`, `topRight`, `bottomLeft`, `bottomRight`.

Comment: I tried to do resizeLetf from the below code but no luck for me so can you please help me out here?

`void resizeLeft(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      widget.item.size = Size(widget.item.size.width + details.delta.dx, widget.item.size.height);
      var angle = widget.item.rotation;
      var rotationalOffset = Offset(cos(angle) + 1, sin(angle)) * details.delta.dx / 2;
      widget.item.offset -= rotationalOffset;
    });
  }`

Comment: @VishalParmar try using subtraction instead of addition when getting the size. Use the same rotational offset value.